# on_message(message) Refactor this function to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 25 to the 15 allowed. | Python Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Im making a discord.py discord bot and would like to have 3 commands with the `on_message` command, these are comands that I dont want the use of prefix. I have looked everywhere online but cant find an answer to this problem.

This is my error:
[image: Screenshot of error in VScode]

```
on_message(message)
Refactor this function to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 25 to the 15 allowed.
```

And this is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    #Swear filter
    if message.author.bot: return
    if "herobrine" in message.content.lower() or "bob" in message.content.lower():
        await message.delete()
        consequence = random.randint(0,1)
        if consequence == 0:#Frick or heck meme
            await message.channel.send("Sir, one more frick or heck and i'll show you what sharpness IV looks like.")
            #await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('C:\\Users\\max\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Code\\Python\\BigBrian\\BigBrian_3\\Version3_1\\swear.jpg'))
            output_war(message.author.name, "Swear_Word_Used")
        elif consequence == 1:#Shut bird meme
            await message.channel.send("Shut.")
            #await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('C:\\Users\\max\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Code\\Python\\BigBrian\\BigBrian_3\\Version3_1\\shut.png'))
            output_war(message.author.name, "Swear_Word_Used")
        else:
            await client.process_commands(message)
    else:
        #Hello Command
        if message.author.bot: return
    if message.content.lower() == "hello" or message.content.lower() == "hi" or message.content.lower() == "helo" or message.content.lower() == "bonjour":
        hour = datetime.now().hour
        if hour < 9:
            #If its morning
            await message.channel.send(f"Good Morning {message.author.name} :wave:")
            output(message.author.name, "Good Morning")
            await client.process_commands(message)
        elif hour > 16:
            #If its night
            await message.channel.send(f"Good evening {message.author.name} :wave:")
            output(message.author.name, "Good evening")
            await client.process_commands(message)
        elif hour >= 10 and hour <= 15:
            #If its just day
            await message.channel.send(f"Hello, {message.author.name} :wave:")
            output(message.author.name, "Hello")
            await client.process_commands(message)
        else:
            #F in the chat
            if message.author.bot: return
            if message.content.lower() == "f" or message.content.lower() == "F" or message.content.lower() == "ƒ":
                await message.channel.send(message + "in the chat!")
                output(message.author.name, "F")
                await client.process_commands(message)
```

Im using discord.py rewrite to do all this, so if anyone can help it would be amazing; thanks!

Comment: It's basically telling you that the code within the function is hard to read. There's too many if-statements, too many different cases being handled. You can solve it by breaking the logic up into smaller self-contained functions & using those functions within the `on_message()` function. Sonar has some good information on "Cognitive Complexity": https://www.sonarsource.com/docs/CognitiveComplexity.pdf

Comment: Try to reduce the number of times you call `client.process_commands` as well, you have several cases that all call it, that ideally would be reduced down to one call.